# Finding the value of $1.1^{82}$ using $(1+x)^{82}$ to a certain accuracy

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

I found this question in a book.

How many terms of the Maclaurin expansion of $(1+x)^{82}$ are needed to guarantee finding a value of $1.1^{82}$ to an accuracy of $10^{-6}$?

This is how I tried to do it:

We want the Lagrange error to be less than $10^{-6}$:

$$R_{n}(0.1)<10^{-6}$$

Now to find $R_{n}(0.1)$:

$$R_{n}(0.1)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0.1)\cdot0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

After writing the values of ${f^{(n+1)}}(x)$, I find a pattern and say that

$${f^{(n+1)}}(x)=\frac{82!}{(82-n)!}(1+x)^{82-n}$$

$${f^{(n+1)}}(0.1)=\frac{82!}{(82-n)!}(1.1)^{82-n}=\frac{82!(1.1)^{82-n}}{(82-n)!}$$

Now just substitute all of this back to $R_{n}(0.1)<10^{-6}$:

$$\frac{\frac{82!(1.1)^{82-n}}{(82-n)!}\cdot0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}<10^{-6}$$

Great! Now I have an inequality that I can solve. I can't graph this so I just use trial and error (which seems like quite an intensive way to do it, so if anyone has a better way I'd love to know).

$$\frac{\frac{82!(1.1)^{82-n}}{(82-n)!}\cdot0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-10^{-6}<0$$

This seems to work first for $n=28$. That means the highest power of $x$ that I need is 28, so the number of terms in the expansion needs to be $n+1=29$. But the book's answer is

> 30

What am I doing wrong here? I'm still quite new to the power series expansions so if there's anything unclear in my working, please let me know (also, as a side note, the book itself may be wrong, though that isn't very likely I'd assume).

Comment: I think both you and the book are estimating the number of terms needed, and your estimate is lower. A Mathematica computation appears to indicate that the polynomial of degree 27 achieves the desired level of accuracy.

Comment: @CatalinZara wow, thanks for taking the time to try it out! If it helps with understanding, the book states in the question "guarantees to find the value to ...". Since their answer is higher it would be more accurate. However, I used the method that they would have expected me to use, so I'm quite confused about it. I also edited the post to make the question more clear.

Comment: I think, you made an off-by-one error in your formula for $f^{(n+1)}(x).\,$ It gives $f'(x) = (1+x)^{82}.\,$ IMO the LHS should be $f^{(n)}(x).$

Comment: One more remark: Does the book specify whether the accuracy is absolute or
relative (this would roughly a factor $1.1^{82}\approx 2478.56$)?

Comment: @gammatester hmm… to find the error after the nth power for a specific value of x, you need to evaluate Rn(x). And in the formula itself it states that it should be n+1 (because that signifies the next term, which hasn't been expanded to. I believe that's the Lagrange error formula. I also don't know anything about the absolute or relative accuracy (it doesn't mention it in the question). The question was supposed to be a rather simple one :/

Comment: I do **not** mean that you should use $f^{(n)},$ but that your formula is wrong: Substituting $n=0$ should result in $f'(x),\,$  your formula gives $f(x)$ instead. This shift by $1$ is a reason for your result $29$ and the correct derivative formula should give $30.$

Comment: @gammatester Wow. You're right. You found the problem. Thanks a lot! How do I mark this as solved? Maybe you can write that as an answer and I'll mark it as having solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my expanded comment: Your formula for the derivatives is off-by-one; it should be
$${f^{(n)}}(x)=\frac{82!}{(82-n)!}(1+x)^{82-n}$$
and therefore

$$R_{n}(0.1)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0.1)\cdot 0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
=\frac{82!}{(82-n-1)!}(1.1)^{82-n-1}\frac{0.1^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

With this you get $R_{29}=3.16\cdot 10^{-6}$ and $R_{30}=0.48\cdot 10^{-6}.$

Comment: How do we know that $f$'s $(n+1)$th derivative is an increasing function? I mean we are supposed to put 0 instead of 0.1 inside the nth derivative if it is decreasing as we are trying to find the worst case bound. So how do you understand if it is decreasing or increasing?

Comment: And I think that means $n < 82$. But it seems like an assumption.

Comment: @Mathrix It's easy to see that $(1+x)^k$ is an increasing function...if you really have to then you can differentiate it to check that.

Comment: @Ian But if $n > 82$, then this means $(n+1)$th derivative of $(1+x)^{82}$ is a decreasing function as it will start to be derived like $(1+x)^{-k}$. As far as I know it is not about the function itself, it's about its $(n+1)$th derivative. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @Mathrix The $83$rd and higher derivatives are just zero.

Comment: @Ian that's right, thank you.

Comment: @Ian How can we know $n < 82$ so that we put $0.1$ for $c$ and not $0$?

Comment: @Mathrix Well, either you need $n=82$ so that the result is just exact, or some smaller $n$ will turn out to work. You can't really know which way it will go until you run the calculation.

Comment: @Ian Thanks again. I hope lastly: how to find the value of $n$ from the operations above? I know that the whole expression is $\le 10^{-6}$ but I don't know how to find the value of $n$.

Comment: @Mathrix Just trial and error, unless you do some further estimation of the factorials.